# jquery click function doesn't work in internet explorer 7

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this code to create a simple jquery carousel animation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var slide = 1;
$('#arrow-left').click(function() {
    if (slide == 1) {
        $("#slideshow-train").animate({left: '-840'}, 2000);
        slide = 2;
    } else if (slide == 2) {
        $("#slideshow-train").animate({left: '-1680'}, 2000);
        slide = 3;
    } else if (slide == 3) {
        $("#slideshow-train").animate({left: '0'}, 1000);
        slide = 1;
    }
});
});
```

This code works fine in all major browser except Internet Explorer 7! It even works fine in IE6! The problem is that click function doesn't work in IE7 at all. Can anyone please point out what is the problem and how can I solve it?

Here is the demo of page. Just click the left arrow (the right hand button doesn't work :)). It should work in all browsers excerpt IE7.

http://goo.gl/LVnhW

Comment: You'd need to provide your html as well - online demo would be best. For now I can only recommend to double-check for JS errors in your console and check if your html is valid. IE is far less forgiving when it comes to silly errors compared to other browsers.

Comment: I have launched the website online. Check it here http://goo.gl/LVnhW. The left arrow should work fine in all browsers excerpt IE7.

Comment: How did you test in IE6 and IE7 (and i take it you also tested in IE8). Did you run your code on different machines or perhaps different virtual machines? Could it be an error on the specific machine/VM that runs IE7?

Comment: I use IETester... http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("selector").live("click", function() {

});
```

This solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Check out 'http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-animation-issues-ie7-position-relative/' - it states that 'Internet Explorer 7 can have issues with rendering jQuery animations if some of the properties that are to be animated have not already been set with CSS, and the containing block has the position property set to "relative".'

Also like Tom sugested, you should post your HTML/css as well.

Answer (score -1):

well this works for me in IE 7, maybe you should try this jquery plugin http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/